# get the number of redirects from a url in R

Tags: r, curl, httr

I have to extract a feature- the number of redirects, from the url in my dataframe. Is there a way to find the number in R like there is in python:

```
r = requests.get(url)
i=0
    for h in r.history:
                i=i+1
print(i)
```

Comment: You can take a look at that `longurl` does to get to the bottom of things: https://github.com/hrbrmtr/longurl; also `str()` works on most anything, including your the equivalent of your `r` object in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from `httr::GET` is completely undocumented, but the headers etc from redirects seem to appear in the `$all_headers` object:

```
> url = "http://github.com"
> g = httr::GET(url)
> length(g$all_headers)
[1] 2
```

because http redirects to https.  If you go straight to https you dont see a redirect:

```
> url = "https://github.com"
> g = httr::GET(url)
> length(g$all_headers)
[1] 1
```

Comment: For some interesting definition of "completely" `?httr::response`

Comment: Its undocumented in ?GET and none of the "See Also". The examples provide no further lucidation or any clue to go look at `?httr::response`. If I had any clue that even existed I'd have gone filed a bug report by now: "See Also: response" or "Return Value: a response object"

Comment: That's hardly "completely" undocumented.

Comment: Documentation that can't be easily found is not useful documentation. Anyway, issue submitted: https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/551

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `httr::GET` is an `httr::response` object which has the core documentation at `?httr::response`. You can examine the *whole* object with `str()` to see the parts that aren't salient to most R users. It's been documented, like, *forever*. I don't know where folks might be confused that it has no docs. Perhaps heads are above the clouds…perhaps in orbit or space or something.

Since what you want is count of redirects, you *might* **actually** care about **redirects** vs a *naive* count of all the response headers. e.g.

```
res <- httr::GET("http://1.usa.gov/1J6GNoW")
sum(((sapply(res$all_headers, `[[`, "status") %% 300) == 1))
```

That's 3 (and may not be exactly what you want either).

```
length(res$all_headers)
```

is 4 and I *doubt* you should be including 4xx responses in the redirects, but you could be clearer in your question if it is just the number of 3xx's vs total in the HTTP chain.

You might also want to consider:

```
cat(rawToChar(curl::curl_fetch_memory("http://1.usa.gov/1J6GNoW")$headers))
```

count the actual redirects from that (depending on what the actual "mission" is).

Comment: 3xx codes being success status codes right? and 4xx the broken ones?

Comment: `3xx` include "redirect" and `4xx` are "yeah, not so much" : https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html